# Verify Using the Formal Definition

Tags: calculus, limits

What expression should I use to verify using the formal definition of a one sided limit that if $$f(x) = \frac{2}{4-x}$$ then $$\lim_{x \to 4^{+}} f(x) = -\infty$$

where $f(x) < M$ and $M < 0$?

I came up with the solution $$|x-4| < 4 - \frac{2}{M}$$
But that doens't seem correct to me. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $ M<0$ .

You look for $ \eta>0 $ such that for all real $ x $ satisfying $ 0<x-4<\color{red}{\eta} $ , you realise $$\frac{2}{4-x}<M$$

or in a equivalent way

$$x-4<\color{red}{\frac{2}{-M}}$$

So, you just need take
$$\eta=\frac{-2}{M}$$

For example, if $ M=- 20000 $, then you can take
$\eta=0.0001$.
Done.

Comment: Once again, i am going to loose points by some unknowns !@?. but not the end of Corona.

Comment: Your question is usefull (+1).